# Create a new column that normalizes by groups using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df like this:

```
Level <- c('Level_1A','Level_1B','Level_1B','Level_1C','Level_1A','Level_1A','Level_1B','Level_1C','Level_1C')
PT <- c(50,100,150,20,30,40,60,80,90)
df <- data.frame(Level,PT)
```

I am trying to create a new column in df that has normalized values of column PT with grouping by Level

**My desired output is**

```
     Level  PT   NORM
1 Level_1A  50 1.0000
2 Level_1B 100 0.4444
3 Level_1B 150 1.0000
4 Level_1C  20 0.0000
5 Level_1A  30 0.0000
6 Level_1A  40 0.5000
7 Level_1B  60 0.0000
8 Level_1C  80 0.8571
9 Level_1C  90 1.0000
```

I am trying to do something like this but it isn't working as expected.

```
normalit<-function(m){
  (m - min(m))/(max(m)-min(m))
}

df$NORM <- df %>%
  group_by(Level) %>%
  summarise(PT = normalit(PT))
```

Please provide some inputs on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line should be `mutate(NORM = normalit(PT))` not `summarise()`, and the assignment should be `df <-` not `df$NORM <-`.

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(Level) %>%
    mutate(NORM = normalit(PT))
```

But you could also avoid doing `df <- df ...` by using the *magrittr* compound assignment operator.  This will pipe `df` into the expression and also update `df` all in one go.

```
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
    group_by(Level) %>%
    mutate(NORM = normalit(PT))
```

Both will give `df` as

```
     Level    PT      NORM
    (fctr) (dbl)     (dbl)
1 Level_1A    50 1.0000000
2 Level_1B   100 0.4444444
3 Level_1B   150 1.0000000
4 Level_1C    20 0.0000000
5 Level_1A    30 0.0000000
6 Level_1A    40 0.5000000
7 Level_1B    60 0.0000000
8 Level_1C    80 0.8571429
9 Level_1C    90 1.0000000
```

You ask about *data.table* in the comments, so here's the code to do it that way.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, NORM := normalit(PT), by = Level]
```

Comment: Is data.table faster than dplyr for doing the same in a large dataset?

Comment: @Sharath - It might be, yes.  Can't say for certain without testing it.  But the code for that is `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, NORM := normalit(PT), by = Level]`.

Comment: Thanks for those different techniques. I am going to apply these to my larger dataset and see which works better for me. :-)

Comment: @Sharath -sure, no problem.  Happy to help.